# How to use hashbang?

Tags: angular

I want to use hash in angular routes. I tried to find but all examples are for oldest version.  Any suggestion how can i do that?

I tried this:

```
let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(NgModule);
let http = injector.get(Http);
let authService = new AuthService(new LocalStorage(), http);

  providers: [ {provide:AuthService,useValue:authService}, // over here 
    SharedService,DatePipe],
```

But im getting error:

> Can not find local storage, can not find AuthService and i can not use
>   NgModule in ReflectiveIncjector.

Any suggestion how can i use hashbang?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `@NgModule` you use `useHash:true`:

```
imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot([
       ...
      ]
      ,{ useHash: true }
  )],
```

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-hashlocationstrategy-

Comment: but this is not the hashbang `#!`